# How to Format a String Using PHP sscanf()

Tags: php, formatting

I am trying to understand how the sscanf() function works in PHP

In both code snippits below, I do not get any formatted output. What I am doing wrong with the sscanf() function?

Thanks

Snipit #1

```
<?php
$input = '1235551234';
sscanf($input, "%3s%3s$4s", $a, $b, $c);
echo '(' . $a . ') ' . $b . '-' . $c;
?>
```

Returns: () -

Smipit #2

```
<?php
$input = 1235551234;
sscanf($input, "%3s%3s$4s", $a, $b, $c);
echo '(' . $a . ') ' . $b . '-' . $c;
?>
```

Returns: () -

Comment: `sscanf` is used to parse. And you should probably use `"%3s%3s%4s"` (`%` instead of `$`).

Comment: my bad...never saw that I inadvertently used the dollar sign. Thanks @Sylvain Defresne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sscanf($input, "%3s%3s$4s", $a, $b, $c);
                      ^---- typo? should be %?
```

With that `$`, it's probably looking for literal char sequence `$`, `4`, `s` which isn't present in your number.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. You had mistake in format.

```
    $input = '1235551234';
    sscanf($input, "%3s%3s%4s", $a, $b, $c); // good
 // sscanf($input, "%3s%3s$4s", $a, $b, $c); // bad

    echo '(' . $a . ') ' . $b . '-' . $c;
```